# MCDA, Fuzzy analytic hierarchy process(FAHP), how to integrate user input data based on criteria into AHP calculation

Tags: fuzzy, expert-system, ahp

i am developing a website that gives the best recommendation of school for all student using Fuzzy AHP(analytic hierarchy process). and i have a problem on how to integrate student data into my AHP calculation.

To my knowledge AHP gives the ranking of alternatives based on a Pairwise Comparison between each criteria, sub-criteria and alternatives from a scale of 1-9 and it's reciprocal.

let's say i have a criteria of Money(A) and Performance(B).
Sub-Criteria of Income is : Income(A1).
Sub-Criteria of Performance is : Test Score(B1) and Absent(B2).

and i have Alternative of School X, School Y and School Z

The end result of AHP would be something like

School X : 25%  |  School Y : 57%  |  School Z : 18%

that means the best recommended school is Y.

but that solution is purely based on the Pairwise Comparison Matrix.
what i want is to have the student input each sub criteria for example :

1. Andy :  Income = $500, Test Score = A, Absent = 0.
2. Susan :  Income = $1200, Test Score = C, Absent = 5.

based on that input the system calculate the best alternative for each of them. maybe it'll output Andy is best suited for School X and Susan is best suited for School Z.

is it possible with Fuzzy AHP or maybe i should use other MCDA Method?

i have tried to give ordinal scale to the user input
`Income < 500 -> 1`
`500 < Income <1000 -> 2`
`1000 < Income -> 3`

`A <= Test Score <= B -> 3`
`C <= Test Score <=D -> 2`

And so on for all criteria.
by then i would have something like :

1. Andy :  [1, 3, 2].
2. Susan :  [3, 2, 2].

i thought of multiplying it with the Sub-criteria Priority Vector, but it doesn't turn out the way i thought it would, and now i'm stuck.
most reference would have this kind of input for the alternative.

Your help would be much appreciated.